# Trying to group and order with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose that I have a table like this:

```
CustomerID | Customer Name | Category | Price
A1           Name1           Cat1       10
A2           Name2           Cat2       20
B1           Name3           Cat1       40
A1           Name1           Cat2       50
A2           Name2           Cat2       5
```

I want to group and sort this dataframe according to CustomerID and Sum of Price for each Customer as the each group will be grouped and sorted by Category, like this:

```
CustomerID | Customer Name | Category | Price |
       A1          Name1          Cat2      50
                                  Cat1      10
       B1          Name2          Cat1      40
       A2          Name2          Cat2      25


df.groupby(["Customer ID", "Customer Name", "Category"]).apply(lambda x: x['PRICE'].sum()).reset_index(name="Sum").sort_values(by="Customer ID",ascending=False)
```

this  code that i wrote doesn't work.

Comment: Can you put your data in text form as well? What is your error message? And you have a typo in your text as well `CustomerID` and `Customer ID`

Comment: How can I put data in text form?  Customer ID is right.

Comment: df.groupby(["CustomerID", "CustomerName", "Category"],as_index=False).Price.sum()

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to simply use the `sum()` method as opposed to using a lambda function -

```
df.groupby(["Customer ID", "Customer Name", "Category"]).sum().reset_index().sort_values(by="Customer ID",ascending=False)
```

Also, doing each step of your operation one at a time and ensuring your result is what you expect is a good way of solving issues such as this one.

Comment: I think the lambda function would work if you just used `lambda x: x.sum()`, but @doktakay's approach is the way to go.